# android: gson performance

Tags: android, performance, gson

I am trying to use gson to do my object mapping on the android emulator.

It has been ridiculously slow when processing json data around 208 kb. I do not have any hierarchies in my json.

After the object mapping is done, i can see it that gson created around 500 records.

It is taking it over 3 minutes on the android emulator to map the input json.

I have annotated my entity which comprises of strings and couple of floats.

An I missing something?

Any ideas, best practices would greatly help.

Are there any ways of quickly object mapping the json data?

```
        URL myURL = new URL(url);
        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        long tickCount = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Policy[] policies = new Gson().fromJson(reader, Policy[].class);
        long endCount = System.currentTimeMillis() - tickCount;
        Log.d("Time to pull policies in milliseconds", "" + endCount);
```

Comment: Please don't use the Android emulator for performance measurement. It's performance model is significantly different from that of a real device.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen questions like this come up before, and the general consensus is that [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is much faster than Gson.  See the following links for more information:

- [Jackson Vs. Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson)
- [Replace standard Android JSON parser for better performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502807/replace-standard-android-json-parser-for-better-performance)
- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/12/entry_345.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Here is one which specifically discusses Android: http://ubikapps.net/?p=525

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the mixing the GSON streaming parser with the Gson object? http://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming (look for the Mixed read example).

This approach may help since Gson reads in an entire parse tree and then acts on it. With a large array list, reading in all elements and attempting to parse may cause lot of memory swaps (or thrashing). This approach will read in one element at a time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 - the DOM approach on GSON is quick to implement, but really slow to process large responses. I use it for prototypes, and then optimise down to the Streaming method for production. I think more people need to realise GSON is not so slow, its how you use it (not saying it is the fastest, just that many don't use streaming)

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably get better performance if you wrapped that `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream` with a nice big buffer...

3 minutes is insane. I seldom run the emulator but I have an app with a ~1.1MB JSON asset and that takes around 5 seconds to load and process on hardware.

(Which is still far too long, but still).

Comment: I am fighting with the same issue. Do you have an online tutorial which descripes your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I can speed up gson.fromJSON quite considerably by not modelling all the elements in the JSON that I won't need. GSON will happily fill in only what is specified in your response classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that CREATING a Gson instance is a very expensive operation, both in terms of CPU used and memory allocated.

Since Gson instances are thread-safe, constructing and reusing a single static instance pays off, especially if you are serializing / deserializing often.