# Is there an equivalent to SimpleXML for parse JSON on Android?

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse a JSON directly from a predefined object. The SimpleXML library can do this thing perfectly but for XML files.

**Is it therefore a library that can do this on Android?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 main JSON parsers used on Android: Jackson and GSON. [This article](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/) contains info on both. Personally, I prefer Jackson as according to [test benchmarks](http://www.martinadamek.com/2011/02/04/json-parsers-performance-on-android-with-warmup-and-multiple-iterations/), it's faster than GSON.

Also, [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261012/android-gson-performance) discusses the GSON performance. You might find it useful ...

Comment: Benchmark resources are down!

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this one:
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

It converts automatically JSON objects to native java classes.

Answer (score 0):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is another kind of java library, that was designed to make 2-way conversions json<-> objects. Performance of this library is quite similar to gson.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added more info. Thx